# Hide Status Code from response header in tomcat

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat

Hi i am using rest service to develop java web application. I am using apache tomcat server. Now when i send request to my app and gets the result. Then following things can be seen in response header:

```
Status: 200 Ok
Content-Type: application/json
Date: (Whatever date is)
Server: Test
Transfer-Encoding: chunked.
```

Firstly i tried to remove Server tag from above info. I searched for that and finally reached this point that i cant remove it. But i can change server name so i did that. (Renaming server name to Test).

Now i want that Status should not be displayed in response header. I searched for that but was unable to find any way. Can i prevent this status from being displaying?

Regards

Comment: Dare I ask why you want to remove valid and useful headers?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the "status header" because it's part of HTTP.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
Header: Value 
etc....
```

The status is directly in the response. It wouldn't make sense to remove the status. The RFC state that a proper response contains a status code.

> 6 Response
>
> After receiving and interpreting a request message, a server
>   responds    with an HTTP response message.
>
> ```
>    Response      = Status-Line               ; Section 6.1
>                    *(( general-header        ; Section 4.5
>                     | response-header        ; Section 6.2
>                     | entity-header ) CRLF)  ; Section 7.1
>                    CRLF
>                    [ message-body ]          ; Section 7.2
> ```

The Status-Line is :

> 6.1 Status-Line
>
> The first line of a Response message is the Status-Line, consisting
>   of the protocol version followed by a numeric status code and its
>   associated textual phrase, with each element separated by SP
>   characters. No CR or LF is allowed except in the final CRLF sequence.
>
> ```
>    Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP Reason-Phrase CRLF
> ```

From my understanding of the RFC, if you don't send the `Status-Code`, you are not respecting the HTTP RFC and therefore not "speaking" `HTTP` which is what an http browser is speaking.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

If you want to send strange response to an http client, you might want to do a custom socket program that will listen on port 80 and send whatever response you want.

Here is a resource that help you build a socket server in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html